# Toggling Classes Voids the Event function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I thought this would work, but whenever I click on the element with the class name of one and it changes to the class named two, I can't get the second event to work. What am I missing here?

```
//first event
$('.one').on('click', function () {

  $('.one').attr('class', 'two');

});


//second event
$('.two').on('click', function () {

  $('.two').attr('class', 'one');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not more simple `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/XZeNE/1/ **or** this http://jsfiddle.net/4mJJe/

use API - `toggleClass`

Further HTML CHange **Dmeo** http://jsfiddle.net/vuLQK/1/

**code**

```
$('.one').on('click', function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('two');

});​
```

**HTML change**

```
$('.one').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass(function(){
           if($(this).hasClass('two'))
               $(this).html('NOw its class two HTML HULK');
           else                 
              $(this).html('CLASS ONE HTML IRONMAN' );

             return "two";            
        })

});


​
```

Comment: Wouldn't the .one element still hold the class name .one when you toggle the class?

Comment: Yep updated second demo as well, not sure the scope of it You are use `removeAttr` when needed `:)`

Comment: @jason328 NO worries `:)` Glad it helped bruv!!

Comment: One quick question. If I wanted to change the html whenever I switch the classes, I thought I could use this `$(this).html('Now class is two')toggleClass('two');` and it does work once but if I click on the button again the html event handler doesn't work.

Comment: @jason328 Cool gimme 2 mins will flick you a demo for that, see you soon!

Answer (score 2):

You need to delegate the event to a **static parent**..
The problem is , because you seem to dynamically change the class you need to bind the event every single time you change the class.. So delegating it should remove this problem..

Also You can write this as a Single event..

```
$('body').on('click','.one' , '.two', function() {

     if( $(this).hasClass('one'){
          function1();
     }
     else if( $(this).hasClass('two'){
         function2();
     }
     $(this).toggleClass('one two');
});
```

Comment: Can simply use API: `toggleClass` :) **now** ++1 By the way!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.on` to attach to one of the ancestors of the 2 elements and then use the selector argument to match the event target.  The selectors won't match elements that aren't present when the handlers are bound.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
        $("#container").delegate(".one", "click", function () {
            $(this).attr('class', 'two');
        });
        $("#container").delegate(".two", "click", function () {
            $(this).attr('class', 'one');
        });
    })
```

Comment: It's a good practice to explain your solution for the user who asked the question and for the SO community.